# CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL memory usage

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf, cgpdfdocument

Hi every one  i am here to clarify my doubt it might be silly for most of them but i need it for my app.my question is while writing the below line  CGPDFDocumentRef myDocumentRef= CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(pdfUrl); how much memory will it take like what ever the size of the pdf size or any other.Of course i am releasing  the CGPDFDocumentRef using CGPDFDocumentRelease(myDocumentRef). Can any one please give an idea how much memory CGPDFDocumentRef can it use.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file size has very little to do with how much memory `CGPDFDocument` consumes. The call to `CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL` will actually allocate very little memory because it's just reading some metadata (title of the document, number of pages...).

You will see the memory usage increase when you actually do something with the document, like rendering a page, because then all the images, fonts, etc. have to be loaded from the file into memory. This does not however depend directly on the file size because the document (or just parts of it) might be compressed, some resources could be shared by multiple pages, etc.